# Why does outerWidth give different values for some websites?

Tags: javascript

I wonder why `window.outerWidth` gives me a bigger value at Stackoverflow.com than at other websites in my browser. I have just noticed this behaviour only on Firefox and Stackoverflow. Shouldn't it be the same on all websites?

In MDN Web Docs it says:

> Window.outerWidth read-only property returns the width of the outside
> of the browser window. It represents the width of the whole browser
> window including sidebar (if expanded), window chrome and window
> resizing borders/handles.

**Example outerWidth at fullscreen:**

- Stackoverflow: 2070
- Discord.com *and the others in my tabs*: 1863

So far I haven't found any website that has a similar behaviour.

```js
console.log( window.outerWidth )
```

#### steps to to reproduce it

1. visit stackoverflow.com
2. open Developertools / Console
3. write window.outerWitdh
4. visit google.com or other side
5. write window.outerWitdh in the console

In **Firefox 95** on **Ubuntu 18.04 lts** these two values are different. Stackoverflow has a larger value.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you're describing (albeit, using different sites, not Discord.com). Can you give us better reproduction steps, such as some known URLs that exhibit the problem more clearly?

Comment: Maybe you have some plugin? Or viewing sites on mobile preview..?

Comment: @Dai i updated my question, with `steps to to reproduce it`

Comment: @MaikLowrey Your repro steps don't work for me: I'm using Firefox 95 on Windows 10, I get the same `window.outerWidth` value for StackOverflow.com and Google.com

Comment: @Dai firefox 95 on Ubuntu 18

Comment: @Dai ok. thank you for testing.

Comment: "Linux" is not a helpful description. **Exactly** what distribution are you running? And what Window Manager? A screenshot or video at your-end would help too.

Comment: It's pretty uncommon to have 2070 and 1863 px of screen width. What's your screen resolution? And what's the zoom your OS is applying to it?

Comment: @NicolaScionti that it! I had zoom on Stackoverflow.  , i will delete this question. thanks guys!

Comment: Don't delete please, can be useful for others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You are running StackOverflow.com at 90% zoom.

  - Assuming that 2070px is your browser windows' actual width on your desktop, then if you multiply that by 0.9 (90%) then you get 1863px (`2070 * 0.9 == 1863`).
- When you run Firefox at different zoom level, Firefox multiplies all other measurements of the page's environment (including the browser and viewport) so the page doesn't actually know it's being zoomed.
- Reset your zoom level in all your Firefox tabs to 100% and then numbers will match.